# Add an Object in an array of Objects Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I need to add an object identified by a key in an array that specifies the id in the `course` property.

The Array

```
[{
  "course": 1035, <- The id to find in the objects
  "start_time": "2018-01-04T20:55:00Z",
  "end_time": "2018-01-04T22:00:00Z",
  "details": { <- it has to be created
    <- here the corresponding object according to the id, 
        in this case 1035
  }
 }, {
  "course": 1106,
  "start_time": "2018-01-04T21:00:00Z",
  "end_time": "2018-01-04T22:00:00Z",
}]
```

The Objects

```
{
  "1035": {
    "id": 1035,
    "title": "Some Title1",
    "slug": "live-show",
    "free": true,
    "order": 0,
    "color": "#CB13A1"
  },
  "1106": {
    "id": 1106,
    "title": "Some Title2",
    "slug": "live-show",
    "free": true,
    "order": 0,
    "color": "#CB13A1"
  }
}
```

The expected result

```
[{
  "course": 1035,
  "start_time": "2018-01-04T20:55:00Z",
  "end_time": "2018-01-04T22:00:00Z",
  "details": {
    "id": 1035,
    "title": "Some Title1",
    "slug": "live-show",
    "free": true,
    "order": 0,
    "color": "#CB13A1"
  }
 }, {
  "course": 1106,
  "start_time": "2018-01-04T21:00:00Z",
  "end_time": "2018-01-04T22:00:00Z",
  "details": {
    "id": 1106,
    "title": "Some Title2",
    "slug": "live-show",
    "free": true,
    "order": 0,
    "color": "#CB13A1"
  }
}]
```

Comment: see if one the answers solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One-liner without mutating your objects/arrays (which is generally a bad idea).

```
target.map(item => Object.assign({}, item, { details: source[item.course]}));
```

where `target = The Array` and `source = The Objects`

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr =[{
  "course": 1035, 
  "start_time": "2018-01-04T20:55:00Z",
  "end_time": "2018-01-04T22:00:00Z",
  "details": {
  }
 }, {
  "course": 1106,
  "start_time": "2018-01-04T21:00:00Z",
  "end_time": "2018-01-04T22:00:00Z",
}];

var obj = {
  "1035": {
    "id": 1035,
    "title": "Some Title1",
    "slug": "live-show",
    "free": true,
    "order": 0,
    "color": "#CB13A1"
  },
  "1106": {
    "id": 1106,
    "title": "Some Title2",
    "slug": "live-show",
    "free": true,
    "order": 0,
    "color": "#CB13A1"
  }
};

arr.forEach(item=>{ 
       item.details = obj[item.course];
  });
console.log(arr);

/*RESULT:
[
  {
    "course": 1035,
    "start_time": "2018-01-04T20:55:00Z",
    "end_time": "2018-01-04T22:00:00Z",
    "details": {
      "id": 1035,
      "title": "Some Title1",
      "slug": "live-show",
      "free": true,
      "order": 0,
      "color": "#CB13A1"
    }
  },
  {
    "course": 1106,
    "start_time": "2018-01-04T21:00:00Z",
    "end_time": "2018-01-04T22:00:00Z",
    "details": {
      "id": 1106,
      "title": "Some Title2",
      "slug": "live-show",
      "free": true,
      "order": 0,
      "color": "#CB13A1"
    }
  }
]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
Object.keys(object).map(key => {
  const obj = object[key]
  // here, you can add all missed keys to your object
  return obj
})
```